# How can open dialog in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create chrome extension that I can open dialog when click on icon example. I tried to use content script but it only work when I open new tab

[image: example]

Comment: That's a context menu, not a dialog?

Comment: This is the popup that you declare via browser_action (ManifestV2) or [action](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/action) (ManifestV3) key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have example how to use popup? when in put action in manifest file, it only show very small popup

Comment: There are many examples around, also in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

In your **manifest.json** file

```
{
  "name": "Get a popup panel",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Open my own popup panel",
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
}
```

In you **popup.html** file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>My content here</body>
</html>
```

And in you **background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(){
    // show here your welcome page
});
```